# Form designer started displaying my forms like they are zoomed in

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My form designer looked fine for the longest time.  All of a sudden the form designer started displaying my forms like they are zoomed in.

I've reset all my settings and still have the issue.  I don't see zoom controls
I found a post of VS2013 about Windows 10 display settings changing the size of text, etc.. but that doesn't do anything. (Mine is at 100% and tried playing with the settings).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried using Ctrl + - and/or Ctrl + + to modify the zoom properties?

Comment: You might have scrolled with the mouse while holding the Ctrl button.

Comment: Look under your "display settings" in windows, there is a slider, check if it is >125%

Comment: On the bottom left of designer panel you should have drop-down with list of different zoom %s, reset it to 100%.

Comment: Your question title is a meaningless repetition of tag information. Instead, it should describe the question you're asking or problem you're having in a way that will be useful to a future user here who sees it in a search result. Please [edit] to make it more clear what you're asking (and remove the information that you can provide in the tags). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for that, 1st time posting and appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it builds properly then it's just settings in your IDE. Reset Visual Studio settings by going to Tools>Import and Export>Reset all settings.

Make sure you save all your projects before you run this utility and know where you saved them to. This will clear your recent projects quick access list as well.

Comment: That didn't work.  Good idea though.

Comment: @McGinn Define "didn't work."

Comment: going to Tools>Import and Export>Reset all settings didn't work... aka didn't do anything to fix my problem.

Comment: does the application also look differently when you build and run it? If so, you may have actually changed your UI appearance.

Comment: No my application doesn't look different when run, it looks the same.

Comment: I have no issue with my application when I run it... only in designer.. so I can't make GUI changes because I can't predict the change in size/positioning

Comment: OK THIS WORKED!!!  Thanks!  I had to reboot after doing this in order for it to work for some reason, but now it works so thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got that sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If your editor size is Zoomed In you can decrease size using Zoom Out option of visual studio in bottom left section.

If your controls are coming zoomed out you can decrase them by right clicking on Form properties and check Font property inside that there will be a size option that you can increase/reduce as per your requirement.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I don't see any options in the bottom left

Comment: I see what you mean now, but that's only available for the code pages, not the designer page